# Gas pressure forces in metal gas bottles looks too big for my layman's mind. Are my numbers wrong?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, pressure

I am trying to understand how much force is acting on a gas bottle in a measurement that I can grasp. (Like on TV, size of stuff are often measured in 'football fields' or 'jumbo jets').

So I have a standart gas bottle which I want to fill with some gas, maybe compressed air.
[image]

And I have read *somewhere in the forums* that similar gas bottles can safely contain pressures of **125 psi**; even number **375 psi** is mentioned:
[image]

So when I use such bottle with 300 psi of compressed stuff I want see how much torment I put on my bottle. First I calculate area of bottle using this formula:

[image]

So I approximate 2600 square inches, and each inch is pressed with 300 pounds of force.
That is 2600 x 300 = 780000 pounds!!! In metric wording: over 350 tones are interrogating integrity of this bottle.
My car weighs only 0.8 tone. It is like stacking 430 of my cars on top of each other, or 6 Abrahams tanks to convince it to explode, and still this bottle wouldn't budge.

Are they really so strong? How?

Almost 400 tones!

Answer (score 2):

The pressures inside a gas canister are high, but not ridiculously high - according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submarine) a steel-hulled submarine can withstand pressures of up to 580 psi.

The key thing to note is that the pressure is applied uniformly across the whole surface of the canister - so it is not at all like placing a stack of cars or 6 tanks on top of the cylinder. The cylinder is designed and manufactured to avoid stress concentrations and weak points - for example, its end caps are rounded rather than flat to avoid sharp bends in the metal. So it can withstand high forces that are applied uniformly across its surface, whereas the same force concentrated in a smaller area would puncture the cylinder.